# Find values in a tree - type checking SML

Tags: types, tree, pattern-matching, sml, smlnj

I need to write my own datatypes - either, and eitherTree, which have their own types. With these, I need to create a function, that takes an int, and an eitherTree as parameters, that searches through the tree, and returns true if the value exists in the tree. the type needs to be: eitherTree -> int -> bool

So far I have :

```
datatype either = ImAString of string | ImAnInt of int
datatype eitherTree = eLEAF of either | eINTERIOR of (either*eitherTree*eitherTree)

fun eitherSearch v1 (eLEAF((v2)) = if v1 = v2 then true
                                            else false
    | eitherSearch v1 (eINTERIOR(e1, et1, et2)) = if v1 = e1 then true
                                              else if (eitherSearch v1 et1) = true
                                              then true
                                              else if  (eitherSearch v1 et1) = true
                                              then true else false
```

The "trick" seems to be casting ImAnInt / int to one another so I can compare them. Anyone have any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pattern matching on the entire parameter; you don't need to limit yourself to the outermost constructor.

```
fun eitherSearch v1 (eLEAF (ImAnInt v2)) = v1 = v2
  | eitherSearch v1 (eLEAF _) = false
  | ...
```

Or you can write a comparison function:

```
fun equalInt (v, ImAnInt v') = v = v'
  | equalInt _ = false

fun eitherSearch v1 (eLEAF v2) = equalInt(v1, v2)
  | ...
```

On a side note,

```
if E then true else false
```

is a very roundabout way of writing `E`,

```
if E1 then true else E2
```

is usually written

```
E1 orelse E2
```

and you never need to compare a boolean with `true` or `false` – `e = true` is equivalent to `e`  and `e = false` is equivalent to `not e`.